# How to clear input response autocomplete and add new value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui-autocomplete

My code autocomplete(Javascript) is like this :

```
$(function()
{
    $( "#nmsakun" ).autocomplete({
        source: "autocomplete",
        minLength: 3,
        select: function(event, ui) {
            var data = ui.item.value.split("#separator#");
            $('#kdsakun').val(data[0]);
            $('#nmsakun').val(data[1]);
            $('#kdgiat').val(data[2]);
            $('#nmgiat').val(data[3]);
            $('#kdoutput').val(data[4]);
            $('#nmoutput').val(data[5]);
            $('#kdakun').val(data[6]);
            $('#nmakun').val(data[7]);
            $('#kdprogram').val(data[8]);
            $('#nmprogram').val(data[9]);
            $('#kdfungsi').val(data[10]);
            $('#nmfungsi').val(data[11]);
            $('#kdsfungsi').val(data[12]);
            $('#nmsfungsi').val(data[13]);
        }
    });
});  
Res
```

response json (ui.item.value) is like this : http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?id=b9b8c0f40a222d063fbc64ea094b9eca

The interface is like this : https://postimg.org/image/srbma7zuv/
[image: Json code]

I mark the text input blue paint, it should be populated with `data[1]`, which is `Werving Bintara`. But, it displays all the response record.

Is there any solution to solve my problem?

Comment: I don't understand why you've mixed both jQuery autocomplete with the code that extrapolates content from the separator.  Shouldn't those be split up, to aid in `console.log` troubleshooting?  `autocomplete` should be an array of values... what is it here?

Comment: @zipzit, Look the json : http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?id=b9b8c0f40a222d063fbc64ea094b9eca. It's array of values.

Comment: See [this link](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data). You need not to concatenate your data with a custom separator. You can directly use JSON results in autocomplete.

Comment: Are u sure blue marked item is `#nmsakun`?

Comment: @Novice, Yes, I sure.